# Argument of type 'HardhatEthersSigner' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Signer | undefined'

Tags: hardhat, unittesting, typescript

I'm writing unit tests for an ERC20 token in TypeScript. I'm getting this error from TypeScript:

> Argument of type 'HardhatEthersSigner' is not assignable to parameter
> of type 'string | Signer | undefined'.

Here's my code:

```typescript
import { assert, expect } from "chai";
import { deployments, ethers } from "hardhat";
import { MyToken } from "../../typechain-types";
import { SignerWithAddress } from "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers/signers";
import { Signer } from "ethers";

const INITIAL_SUPPLY = 20;

describe("MyToken Unit Test", function () {
  let myToken: MyToken;
  let deployer:SignerWithAddress;
  let userOne: SignerWithAddress;

  beforeEach(async function () {
    const accounts = await ethers.getSigners();
    deployer = accounts[0];
    userOne = accounts[1];

    await deployments.fixture("all");
    myToken = await ethers.getContract("MyToken", deployer);
  });

  .
  .
  .

});
```

I have tried typecasting from `SignerWithAddress` to `Signer` but it does not work. I also tried making `deployer` a union type by using `let deployer:Signer|SignerWithAddress;` but it doesn't work either.

So far the only solution I have is making the `deployer`'s type as `any` but it's not a good practice.

Additional information:

Solidity compiler version: 0.8.21

Comment: Running into the same issue just now. Will post if I find a solution....

Comment: Seems related to this issue I created: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/issues/574

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran into this and then another issue related to the [v6 migration](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/151234/followed-hardhat-test-tutorial-and-got-typeerror-0-ethers-1-getaddress-is). Once I installed ethers as a dependency (`yarn add -D ethers`), I was able to get this to work.