# Unable to deploy the smart contract from my terminal using hardhat

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, ethers.js, hardhat

I've created one contract and trying to deploy it locally to test it. But it's not deploying. It throws this error,
[image]

This is the code in scripts/deploy.js file,

```
async function main() {
  const tracking = await hre.ethers.deployContract("Tracking");

  await tracking.waitForDeployment();

  console.log(`Tracking deployed to ${tracking.target}`);
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

My contract name and filename is Tracking and Tracking.sol

This is the hardhat and ethers versions I'm using,

```
    "hardhat": "^2.17.4",
```

Since I'm new to blockchain development I don't know why this error is coming, any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Same question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/151234/followed-hardhat-test-tutorial-and-got-typeerror-0-ethers-1-getaddress-is

Answer (score 0):

you can do following step for remove error

step 1: delete node module folder
step 2: change ether version in package.json to ^6.7.1
step 3: run below code in cmd

```
npm install
```

step 4: after run your js script there is no error in js script
after that if error come then its problem

check where is ether_1.getAddress function
because in your cmd error says this is not a function

try this example

> Greeter.sol

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Greeter{
    string private greeting;

    constructor(){
        greeting="hello,world";
    }

    function greet() public view returns(string memory){
        return greeting;
    }

    function setGreeting(string memory _greeting) public {
        console.log("The greeting will be changed from %s to %s",greeting,_greeting);
        greeting=_greeting;
    }
}
```

> deploy.js

```
async function main() {
  const greeter = await hre.ethers.deployContract("Greeter");
  await greeter.waitForDeployment();
  console.log(`contract deployed to ${greeter.target}`);
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

deploy this example
because its work in my system